# How to Localize Html email templates

Tags: c#, email, localization

I'm building a localization functionality in an mvc3 app and I have localized the bulk of the application, but there will be email templates, that are html, that I need to localize along with the other application functionality.

Comment: Where is your email content stored?

Comment: there's this star-fangled templating engine called `razor`, you should check it out (along with partial views). the parsed-result of a razor template + view model does not need to be a web page - it could quite easily be a string or JSON

Comment: The Email content is stored in the business layer as a resource reference.